# Translate C# delegates onto TypeScript

Tags: c#, javascript, typescript

Could you tell me how to translate this into `TypeScript`?
using SharpKit.JavaScript;

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [JsType(JsMode.Prototype)]
    public class JsEventArgs
    {
    }

    public delegate void JsEventHandler<in T>(object sender, T args) where T : JsEventArgs;
    public delegate void JsEventHandler(object sender, JsEventArgs args);
}
```

And usage in the other class:

```
public event JsEventHandler<LayerVisivilityEventArgs> Changed;
```

I tried that:

```
module JsEvent {

    export class JsEventArgs {
    }

    public JsEventHandler: (sender: Object, args: any) => void;
    public JsEventHandler: (sender: Object, args: JsEventArgs) => void;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to do. What does SharpKit have to do with TypeScript?

Comment: I'm translating a C# app onto TypeScript. I want to create an event that will work as the one from C# code.

Comment: And what's wrong with the TypeScript you've tried above?

Comment: Aren't delegates a bit like closures? JavaScript supports closures natively. What is there to port?

Comment: I'm getting an error "Check format of expression term." for both JsEventHandlers

Comment: I would think that a delegate is more like a function variable in JavaScript. I presume there's a stronger-typed version of that in TypeScript.

Comment: I think that's because you've added public properties to a module. In TS you can only have properties of a class.

Comment: After removing `public` keyword still the same error:S

Comment: It's not because they are public - it's because you can't add properties to a module.

Comment: The question is not clear at all. That JsEventHandler and JsEventArgs and JsMode — how would anybody guess their purpose? You need to define clearly what are you trying to achieve rather than giving your raw source code out without any explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to stop thinking in C#, and begin thinking in TypeScript.

This code:

```
module JsEvent {

    export class JsEventArgs {
    }

    public JsEventHandler: (sender: Object, args: any) => void;
    public JsEventHandler: (sender: Object, args: JsEventArgs) => void;
}
```

... tries to add two properties to a module, but properties are only permitted on a class (or interface).

TypeScript doesn't really use delegates - you can wire up an event (for example, in JQuery), like this:

```
$('selector').click((e:JQueryEventObject) => {
     // Do something here.
});
```

... or, avoiding JQuery:

```
var div: HTMLDivElement = new HTMLDivElement();
div.onclick = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    // Do something here.
};
```

... or, without an anonymous function:

```
div.onclick = doSomething;
function doSomething(e:MouseEvent):void{
    // Do something here.
}
```

I think the closest pattern you'll get to a delegate is something like this (cribbed from http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/9679-Javascript-Delegates!):

```
module JSEvents {
    class JSEventClass {

        public delegate:(e:string) => any;

        constructor() => {
            this.delegate = this.doSomething;
            this.delegate("Hello, Delegate World");
        }

        public doSomething(e: string): any {
            console.log("Doing Something: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

... but in a TypeScript / JavaScript world, I don't see what this pattern achieves over just calling `doSomething()` directly.

Comment: Encapsulating a common call signature in a delegate is useful for reuse and readability.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a little class which behaves like the .NET Delegate class (which is implicitly created for an event in .NET)

```typescript
export interface IDelegate {
    (sender: any, ...parameters: any[]): void;
}

export class DelegateBuilder {
    private callees: IDelegate[];

    constructor() {
        this.callees = [];
    }

    invoke(sender: any, ...parameters: any[]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.callees.length; i++) {
            var callee = this.callees[i];
            if (caller)
                callee(sender, parameters);
        }
    }

    contains(callee: IDelegate) : bool {
        if (!callee)
            return false;

        return this.callees.indexOf(callee) >= 0;
    }

    add(callee: IDelegate): DelegateBuilder {
        if (!callee)
            return this;

        if (!this.contains(callee))
            this.callees.push(callee);

        return this;
    }

    remove(callee: IDelegate): DelegateBuilder {
        if (!callee)
            return this;

        var index = this.callees.indexOf(callee);
        if (index >= 0)
            this.callees.splice(index, 1);

        return this;
    }

    toDelegate() : IDelegate {
        return (sender: any, ...parameters: any[]) => this.invoke(sender, parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a close translation of the code in question. However, this doesn't address event handling, which is already covered by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15680110/238753).

```
module MyNamespace
{
    export class JsEventArgs
    {
    }

    export interface JsEventHandler<T extends JsEventArgs> {
        (sender: any, args: T): void;
    }

    export interface JsEventHandler {
        (sender: any, args: JsEventArgs): void;
    }
}
```